# What do I put instead of a space when changing directory?

Tags: powershell, cd

C:\Users\First Last\

What do I replace the space with? I've tried multiple variations but nothing works.

C:\Users\First-Last\
C:\Users\First_Last\
C:\Users\First`Last\

Answer (score 2):

add double quotes

```
 cd "C:\Users\First Last\"
```